# How to model relations to other nodes within a single text field?

Tags: database, database-design, neo4j, graph-databases

I have a problem with modelling a specific case in a graph database. It is very similar to @mentions in Facebook, so I hope there is least one good solution.

Example:
I have three nodes, each containing a paragraph from a legal text. Let's assume:

- §1: "Lorem Ipsum 1... please refer to §2 and §3 for further information"
- §2: "Lorem Ipsum 2"
- §3: "Lorem Ipsum 3"

Now I would like that if reading node 1 (=§1), the user is presented with hyperlinks node 2 (§2) and node 3 (§3). While the relation itself is simple to model

> (§2)<-[REFERS_TO]-(§1)-[REFERS_TO]->(§3)

, I have difficulty with "pointing" the relation to a certain text element, i.e. the characters "§2" -> node 2 and "§3" -> node 3.

How could one solve this problem?
I have thought about replacing the text elements with IDs, which are also stored on the relationships,

> §1: "Lorem Ipsum 1... please refer to {@IDXXX} and {@IDYYY} for further information"
>
> (§2)<-[REFERS_TO{ID="IDXXX",LABEL="§2"}]-(§1)-[REFERS_TO{ID="IDYYY",LABEL="§3"}]->(§3)

but I fear that using IDs is too "static" and can cause problems with changing content of node 1 and its relations.

Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 1):

If a paragraph always has the same label (ignoring, for the moment, label changes over time), no matter from where it is referenced, then the `label` property belongs in the paragraph node, not the relationships (which would be a wasteful duplication of information). Also, this way, if a referenced paragraph's label ever needs to change, it only needs to be done in one place -- and the most obvious place.

I don't see any reason for a label "id". And I don't see an issue with changes to the referring paragraph -- it can add, replace, or delete relationships to other paragraphs as appropriate.

Comment: You are right, the label and ID information is redundant (on the relation), because it is the label and ID of the target node! How could I miss that :) Thx

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to model what are essentially embedded hyperlinks. I think the idea of using relationships to link the base node to the node being referenced is also a good idea.

What I recommend is to store start position and stop position attributes on the relationships. These should represent where in the text of the node containing the relationship the reference should start and stop. If its really just more of a footnote type reference you could just use start position.

Yes, whenever you update the text you will have to update the positions but that shouldn't be hard to manage and will be something you have to deal with regardless of how you implement the solution.

Comment: Yes, exactly, "embedded hyperlinks" is the term I was missing!
I like the idea of storing the start and stop position on the relationship. In any case: if the text content changes, I need to parse it again and look for all paragraph references and upsert relations.
What would you think about storing a hash for the original text on the relation and only creating the embedded links for the user, if it fits the current text's hash? Too oversized / Paranoid?

Comment: I wouldn't go that way. If the text changes then the hash is no good and likely will never be good again. Storing the start position of the link (and optionally the end position) is a technique that is typically used by entity extraction software to mark entity positions. It will apply here as well.

If you change the text you need to walk the relationships for the references and determine 1) is the link still valid. If you changed the text referenced by the link it might not be. 2) If the link is still valid you just need to recompute the start position. This should be fairly easy to do